# How to call a maximum available integer for a 64-bit CPU?

Tags: cpu, operating-systems

Say, for 32-bit OS, we say that the largest available integer that the CPU can handle natively is 4,294,967,295, which in "human language" is *4 Gigabytes*.

So for a 64-bit CPU, such number is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615, but how would you call it? *A gazillion*?

Comment: [Related question](http://superuser.com/questions/698312/if-32-bit-machines-can-only-handle-numbers-up-to-232-why-can-i-write-100000000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number is called *4 billion 294 million 967 thousand 295*. Likewise, the larger number is *18 quintillion 446 quadrillion 744 trillion 73 billion 709 million 551 thousand 615* (given in [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales), so not everyone agrees that the first number are "billions" – they'll say it's "milliards").

*4 gigabytes* is the addressable memory range in 32 bit machines (simplified). The term *4 gigabytes* is from the [SI prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix) for billion and just means "4 billion bytes" (similar to 1 kilometer = 1000 meters). So you could call that number "4 giga" if you want to confuse everyone you're talking to.

It's a bit more than 4 billion since we're actually dealing with powers of two rather than powers of 10, so the "kilo" is 1024, not 1000. Alternative [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) exist, so you'd more correctly call this number *4 gibibytes*.

Likewise, the larger number, used as a prefix, would be *16 exa* or *16 exbi*.

[Note that 64 bit CPUs aren't actually able to address this much memory, it's usually "only" a few dozen to a few hundred GB.](https://superuser.com/a/557296/22317)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just curious, why would MS limit the amount of RAM? It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Probably because some marketer somewhere decided that it would be a good idea to get you to buy more expensive editions of Windows.

Comment: That, and as far as the uppermost limit on the highest edition of Windows, they won't support more RAM than they've ever actually tested.

Comment: @MikeF Windows 8 was a desktop OS, and no desktop hardware reached anywhere near 512GB six years ago.  This was, then, a very generous limit.